# How to find transmission speed?

Tags: networking, udp

Two host machine's one as a client and other as a server, i am testing udp load-test in these two machines.Machine Ethernet speed is 100 Mbps but i want to send 30000 packets each of 512 bytes at 1 Mbps speed how to do?  Is their any Linux command to set Ethernet speed at 1 Mbps?

Comment: See e.g. http://superuser.com/questions/66574/how-to-throttle-bandwidth-on-a-linux-network-interface and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection for possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Debian GNU/Linux has **ethtool** and **net-tools** to set ethernet speed.

Example:

- find out your NICs:

```
hwinfo --netcard --short
 network:                                                        
  wlp4s0               Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
  enp5s0               Broadcom NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
```

- find out possible speeds:

```
ethtool enp5s0
 Settings for enp5s0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
```

- you may now set all supported modes like this:

```
ethtool -s enp5s0 speed 100 duplex full
```

Comment: Maybe add some examples of command usage?  As it is this is not quite enough for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use a program called `iperf` for any sort of network related testing
(man page: http://staff.science.uva.nl/~jblom/gigaport/tools/man/iperf.html)

it has switches that allow you to set the speed.  You can also run one in server mode and one in client to accurately test your network.

```
  -a, --tcp_bandwidth \    for TCP, bandwidth to send at in bits/sec
                  #[KM]    (default no bandwidth limit used)
  -b, --bandwidth #[KM]    for UDP, bandwidth to send at in bits/sec
                           (default 1 Mbit/sec, implies -u)
```